# Why is my Console application not showing Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

Very strange issue ... I have 2 console applications in my Solution, Console application 1, does show the Console when i run it and have it set up as the Start up project ... Console Application 2, runs... executes ... but does not display the console.

Here is the code:

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:8080/";

            using (WebApp.Start<StartUp>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                Console.Write("Service Listening at : " + baseAddress);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the class StartUp

```
 public class StartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
            config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the app in the debugger to see if it hits the Console.Write?

Comment: Yes, I have and it does, it actually worked at first and then I made a change to the StartUp and rebuilt it and it did not work after that

Comment: Show us the code for **both** console apps

Comment: Are you certain both projects are configured as "Console application" projects? There is a flag in the PE executable header which tells Windows to display a console window when the program starts, if the flag is not set then no window is displayed, that's why Notepad doesn't display a console window when it runs, but why `cmd.exe` does.

Comment: How do I check for that flag, or set that flag

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel in your Project properties window, where it says "Output type".

Comment: Yes, that worked... thank you so much!!

Answer (score 11):

**Try to close the Visual Studio and open it again**

Maybe this will help others too because the same thing happened to me.

It happened after I debug my ASP.Net Core Project on IIS Express. I close my ASP.Net Core Solution and then open my Console App Solution without closing the Visual Studio but the console won't show up. So I close my Visual Studio then open the solution again and the console showed up.

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.9.20

Comment: Worked for me!!

Answer (score 4):

The launch setting might have been set to IIS Express. Go to the project properties > Debug and change the Launch setting to Project. Make sure to set the Debug Target on the Standard Toolbar to the project as well.

[image: Debug Target]

Answer (score 1):

A console application will terminate when the `Main` method returns unless a child thread is marked as a foreground thread. It's possible that your program runs so quickly you never see the console window being displayed.

`WebApp.Start` is not a blocking method, neither are any of the subsequent calls in your `Main` method.

Simply add a `Console.ReadLine()` call after your "Service listening" message. There is no need for `Thread.Sleep(-1)` because your code is not running in a cooperative-multitasking environment.

Comment: How did it "not work"? Did you observe the same behavior?

Comment: i put in Console.ReadLine(); took out Thread.Sleep(-1); ... pressed cmd 5, it goes directly into Debug mode ... but no window

Comment: I had slightly different symptoms - in debug I saw console, outside debugging I didn't see it but dotnet.exe process was visible and I couldn't compile app without killing the process.
After restarting Visual Studio everything is OK.

Comment: @AndrzejMartyna i had got a problem when VS did not show console window after console application was started by F5. However VS restarted has fixed this, thanks a lot. I have not even think to restart VS before you post

Comment: Visual Studio restart helped me too. had this issue after System.Web.Mvc nuget package update

Comment: Visual Studio restart fixed me up good as well. The simple answer: Thanks for calling tech support, have you tried restarting it?